# Give meta users option to view meta questions within PW area / list of questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm jumping between meta and Pro Webmasters in different tabs in my browser. Wouldn't it be more efficient to give meta users the option to have meta questions and PW questions listed in one interface. Or create tabbed browsing for meta users and let them click between PW and a Meta tab to quickly see questions from both sites?

Comment: All modern browsers have tabs these days. Sometimes it's *nice* to have things separated, and I think this is one example. If I'm in a technical mind I check Stack Overflow. If I'm in a meta-discussion mind I check meta. If I'm in the mood for answering emails, I check my GMail. If I'm bored I check Facebook...

Comment: I'm assuming "PW" stands for "Pro Webmasters"?

Comment: Yes this was migrated from there

Answer (score 3):

I would be *strongly* against this. Blurring the line between a site and it's meta is just confusing and will cause issues like posting meta questions into the main site or vice-versa.

As it is now, that sort of thing *still* happens from time to time and while those off-topic posts are swiftly dealt with, doing things that make that noise more likely are a bad idea.

To top it all off, adding more tabs or widgets to the interface just adds more clutter. You would have to complexify asking a question as well, since it would no longer be clear what "site" you were posting to. The browser chrome already does a good job with tabs and in a way that is consistent across all web sites I use. Let the browser do it's job managing tabs and let the question list interface do what it does best: List the questions *from it's own site*.